# Flutter's google map widget not being clipped by Card or ClipRRect

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fit a google mapview into a card and round off the corners. The only problem is that the view isn't clipping at the corners, despite setting the `Clipping Behaviour` in the card itself and trying multiple combinations of ClipRRect, am I missing something here:

**EDIT**:

I've also tried using a FittedBox and ConstrainedBox in order to make the map sit well but so far it hasn't worked.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          child: Container(
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  semanticContainer: true,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  child:GoogleMap(
                    mapType: MapType.hybrid,
                    initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      controller.setMapStyle(MapStyle.retro);
                      _controller.complete(controller);
                    },
                  ),
              ))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**:

This was actually a bug in the Flutter UiKitView that has since (very recently about 2 days ago) been patched on the master channel.

It was originally tracked by this pull request:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30117

**my code above works** but the solution is to do the following if you have not already done:

In your app directory, run the following commands:

```sh
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter build ios
flutter run
```

*Caution:* this will put you on the **master** channel and off the default *stable* channel, so your mileage may vary.